# What does "\e" do? What does "\e[1;1H\e[2J" do?

Tags: c, macos

I was looking for some alternative to `system("cls")` that works on MacOS and I found this:

```c
printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
```

However I do not know what this is doing.

[Post where I found this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clear-console-c-language/)

Comment: This is not a regexp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences

Comment: [What type of sequences are escape sequences starting with `\033]`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831971/what-type-of-sequences-are-escape-sequences-starting-with-033)

Comment: `"\e"` is not an alphabetic escape sequence described by C11 (see [C11 5.2.2p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.2)). If you need portability, replace with `"\x1B"`, ie `printf("\x1B[1;1H\x1B[2J");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\e` is escape and what that printf() line is telling the terminal to move the cursor to line 1 column 1 (`\e[1;1H`) and to move all the text currently in the terminal to the scrollback buffer (`\e[2J`).

These are ANSI escape codes and here's some resources:
 https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797
[https://bluesock.org/~willkg/dev/ansi.html](https://bluesock.org/%7Ewillkg/dev/ansi.html)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code (suggested by [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman))

Edit: I also recommend the use of `\e[H\e[2J\e[3J` as that is what cls/clear prints. This tells the terminal to move the cursor to the top left corner (`\e[H`), clear the screen (`\e[2J`), and clear the scrollback buffer (`\e[3J`).

Comment: Wikipedia actually has a [great page on ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 0):

if your language does't support `\e` you can instead replace it with `\x1b` or `\033`.
These represent the same byte number, 27, written either in base 16 (hexadecimal) or base 8 (octal) respectively.

As hexidecimal:

```c
printf("\x1b[1;1H\x1b[2J");
```

As octal:

```c
printf("\033[1;1H\033[2J");
```

Answer (score 0):

`\e` is the escape character:

- Unicode code point: U+001B
- When encoded in UTF-8, it is the byte value 27 (or 1B in hexadecimal)

Terminals handle this character differently from normal text. It treats it as an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). For example, this character, followed by the `[` character (U+005B), represents a [control sequence introducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSIsection).

When a control sequence introducer is followed by a character representing a number, the by `;`, then by another number, then by `H`, as in your example, the terminal will move the cursor to the position marked by the two numbers.